# JPA cascading delete for foreign key

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a bidirectinal relatioship mapped as

```
@Entity
public class Customer {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "customer", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Servers> servers;

}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Server {

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "...")
  private Customer customer;

}
```

The problem is that I have a (Oracle) DB enforced foreign key reference in place but when I do a remove on the customer, I end up with an error saying that the @JoinColumn value in the server for the parent relation cannot be set to null.

I have tried various optional attributes, cascade=ALL on the @ManyToOne, @PreRemove methods on the customer (trying to clear the servers list) but to no avail. Instead of first removing all servers for the client, it tried to clear the relation first, resulting in no-goodness.

Thanks in advance,
  Nik

Comment: shouldnt it be manytomany on server ?

Comment: Actually, I should have renamed the Client to Customer from my original case. There are n customers, and each can have n Servers (host machines) but each Server can only belong to one customer ;-) (edited now)

Comment: hmm.. so then shouldn't server-customer be one-to-one ?

Comment: Don't think so, mapping like that appear in most textbook examples of bi-directional 1-n relationships. (I also tried to nullable=false on the @JoinColumn, no go)